# should not include

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I describe RSpec test to check if the array doesn't include some value?  Something like this:

```
tags.should include("one")
tags.should not include("two")
```

I can rewrite my condition:

```
tags.include?("two").should be_false
```

but I'm looking for more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RSpec has `should_not` as well as `should`.

```
tags.should include("one")
tags.should_not include("two")
```

Here  some [more examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-8/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) of the include matcher.

Answer (score 26):

for Rspec v3:

```
expect(my_string).to include "some value"


expect(my_string).not_to include "some value"
```

Comment: This is now preferred syntax over `should`.